# Iteratively concatenate pandas dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am iteratively processing a couple of "groups" and I would like to add them together to a dataframe with every group being identified by a 2nd level index.

This:

```
print pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=["A", "B", "C"])
```

was suggested to me - but it doesn't play well with iteration.

I am currently doing

```
data_all = pd.DataFrame([])
    for a in a_list:
        group = some.function(a, etc)
        group = group.set_index(['CoI'], append=True, drop=True)
        group = group.reorder_levels(['CoI','oldindex'])
        data_all = pd.concat([data_all, group], ignore_index=False)
```

But the last line totally destroys my multi-index and I cannot reconstruct it.

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: I could be misreading the code, but why do you need to `concat` at each iteration of the loop? Can `data_all` just be a list, and you `concat` at the end of the for loop?

Comment: solved! go ahead and write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8):

Should be able just make `data_all` a list and concatenate once at the end:

```
data_all = []
for a in a_list:
    group = some.function(a, etc)
    group = group.set_index(['CoI'], append=True, drop=True)
    group = group.reorder_levels(['CoI','oldindex'])
    data_all.append(group)

data_all = pd.concat(data_all, ignore_index=False)
```

Also keep in mind that pandas' `concat` works with iterators. Something like `yield group` may be more efficient than appending to a list each time. I haven't profiled it though!

Comment: Why is data_all enclosed in brackets in the last line in the loop? Since data_all is already a list, this seems to unnecessarily create a list of lists. Trying to test this, I found that passing a list of lists of dataframes to concat raises "TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object". Also the for loop is unnecessarily indented (as in the OP's post..).